# UserControls - Programmatically setting output caching duration?

Tags: asp.net

I want duration to be configurable from Web.config file, so user can alter the output caching after deployment.

For achieving such purpose I need equivalent C# codebehind snippet of following ASP.NET markup?

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="120" VaryByParam="CategoryName" %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way of programmatically setting cache duration for pages, though I'm not sure if this works for partial caching of user controls:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.VaryByParams["Category"] = true;
Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
```

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323290

You can also add a [PartialCaching() attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z.aspx) to a user control to define caching:

```
[PartialCaching(120)]
public partial class CachedControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    // Class Code
}
```

Though I'm not sure how this could be manipulated programmatically, but it might give you some ideas.

Comment: +1. It was through searching I came across this question and I got my own Question resolved. Just wanted to confirm that the 3rd line above:Response.Cache.VaryByParams["Category"] = true; if omitted then caching will not work. Also while using <% Output %> directive we must specify VaryByParam attribute, else it will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can set output caching using the `Response.Cache` property.

In this case:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(120));
Response.Cache.VaryByParams["Category"] = true;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y18he7cw%28VS.71%29.aspx